# Printf a buffer of char with length in C

Tags: c, buffer, printf

I have a buffer which I receive through a serial port. When I receive a certain character, I know a full line has arrived, and I want to print it with `printf` method. But each line has a different length value, and when I just go with:

```
printf("%s", buffer);
```

I'm printing the line plus additional chars belonging to the former line (if it was longer than the current one).

I read [here](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdio/sprintf/) that it is possible, at least in C++, to tell how much chars you want to read given a `%s`, but it has no examples and I don't know how to do it in C. Any help?

I think I have three solutions:

- printing char by char with a `for` loop
- using the termination character
- or using .*

QUESTION IS: Which one is faster? Because I'm working on a microchip PIC and I want it to happen as fast as possible

Comment: When you've received that *"certain character"* and have appended it to `buffer`, append a null character (`\0`) as well. This "tells" `sprintf()` when to stop printing characters.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

The string you have is not null-terminated, so, `printf` (and any other C string function) cannot determine its length, thus it will continue to write the characters it finds there until it stumbles upon a null character that happens to be there.

To solve your problem you can either:

- use `fwrite` over `stdout`:

  ```
  fwrite(buffer, buffer_length, 1, stdout);
  ```

  This works because `fwrite` is not thought for printing just strings, but any kind of data, so it doesn't look for a terminating null character, but accepts the length of the data to be written as a parameter;
- null-terminate your buffer manually before printing:

  ```
  buffer[buffer_length]=0;
  printf("%s", buffer); /* or, slightly more efficient: fputs(buffer, stdout); */
  ```

  This could be a better idea if you have to do any other string processing over `buffer`, that will now be null-terminated and so manageable by normal C string processing functions.

Comment: I am surprised that answers to duplicates of this SO question do not include this method, but only suggest `for` loops...

Answer (score 63):

You can either add a null character after your termination character, and your printf will work, or you can add a `'.*'` in your printf statement and provide the length

> ```
> printf("%.*s",len,buf);
> ```

In C++ you would probably use the std::string and the std::cout instead, like this:

> ```
> std::cout << std::string(buf,len);
> ```

If all you want is the fastest speed and no formatting -- then use

> ```
> fwrite(buf,1,len,stdout);
> ```

Comment: Perfect. So I have three solutions: printing char by char with a for loop, using the termination character, or using .* QUESTION IS: which one is faster? Because I'm working on a microchip PIC and I want it to happen fast

Comment: @RomanRdgz: my guesses: `fwrite` or null-termination+`fputs` should be the fastest, followed by null-termination+`printf` (could be slower because it may have to parse the format string, unless the compiler is very smart) then `printf` with `.*` (surely needs to parse the format string) and last printing char by char (probably the slowest, because of all the function calls - that however could be inlined).

Comment: Also, your C++ version is quite inefficient, you are allocating/deallocating stuff on the heap (constructing an instance of `std::string`) when a simple call to `cout.write` would be enough. Not that it would matter once in a while on a normal machine, but with very limited resources or in a tight loop it may be noticeable.

Comment: I'm using CCS compiler, and I don't think it has cout.write. That's why I'm using fputs or printf. Thanks for your info @Matteo Italia

Comment: @RomanRdgz: if you have `cout` you'll surely have `cout.write`, anyhow that was just a comment about the C++ solution of @Soren, for C solutions I already wrote my answer :) .

Comment: If all you want is the fastest speed and no formatting -- then use `fwrite(buf,1,len,stdout)`

Comment: PIC - ugh!  Anyway, since you know you are at the end of the line, shove a null in and avoid the printf having to count, (if only to keep the format parsing to a minimum), - that's probably fastest. What are you printing to anyway?

Comment: I am printting to a serial port, with fprintf/fputs/fputc

Answer (score 3):

Once you've identified the end of the line, you must append a `'\0'` character to the end of the buffer before sending it to `printf`.

Comment: Anyone who has downvoted want to explain why so that I can improve my answer?

Comment: You should say what the OP did wrong, in addition to how to correct it.

Answer (score 3):

You can put a NUL (0x0) in the buffer after receiving the last character.

`buffer[i] = 0;`